# How to make separate strings of a variant in shell script

Tags: linux, shell

```
#! /bin/sh

VAR=(fdf fef fef)

for i in ${VAR}; do
        echo i;
done
```

Code above has errors. I want to make shell take VAR as a separate string array, and get the output like this:

```
fdf
fef
fef
```

how to make it happen ? Thanks !

Comment: sh does not have arrays.  Please change your interpreter to a shell which supports arrays.  Using #!/bin/sh for a script that uses non-portable constructs is the root of all evil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
VAR=(aa bb cc)

for i in "${VAR[@]}"
do
        echo $i;
done
```

More info in [this article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-arrays).

Comment: Thanks, it works ! but one more question, how come I can use it by $. test.sh but fail in $./test.sh, the latter output is error...

Comment: zhf@zhf-desktop:~/test$ . ar_test.sh 
aa
bb
cc
zhf@zhf-desktop:~/test$ ./ar_test.sh 
./ar_test.sh: 9: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Comment: @YifanZhang I don't understand the question. Edit your question and add the script that produces that error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452155/how-come-using-shell-sh-get-error-but-shell-sh-works

Answer (score 0):

The proposed solution only works when using bash. He must also have changed or removed the shebang, otherwise you'll get: syntax error: unexpected "(".

See also his follow up question: [How come using ./shell.sh get error but . shell.sh works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452155/how-come-using-shell-sh-get-error-but-shell-sh-works)