# How come using ./shell.sh get error but . shell.sh works

Tags: linux, bash, shell

a shell script:

```
VAR=(aa bb cc)

for i in "${VAR[@]}"
do
        echo $i;
done
```

when run it using `. ar_test.sh`, it works.

```
zhangyf@zhangyf-desktop:~/test$ . ar_test.sh 
aa
bb
cc
```

but fails in this way,

```
zhangyf@zhangyf-desktop:~/test$ ./ar_test.sh 
./ar_test.sh: 9: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

There are other lines in the file, so line 9 is actually VAR=(aa bb cc). I know the difference is that the latter forks a new shell process while the former ones run the script in the current shell, but why does the result differs so much?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference is not a fork, but different shells. `.` sources file in the current shell and `./ar_test.sh` runs executable with default shell (/bin/sh), which may not support arrays. Use shebang as the first line of your script to specify proper shell:

```
#!/bin/bash
...other code goes here...
```

Answer (score 2):

Your current shell is likely to be `bash`. If your shebang-line starts `/bin/sh`, then `VAR=(aa bb cc)` will not work. Using `source` (the `.` command`), the script will run in your current shell (that is,`bash`).

Make sure the first line of your script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Another way to start the script in a new shell is `bash ar_test.sh`.

In response to the heated discussion in the comments: If you want to keep your script portable on systems where bash might not be installed in its standard location, you should put `#!/usr/bin/env bash` as first line instead.

Comment: There's clever lazy, and there's stupid lazy. Writing `#!/usr/bin/env bash` takes maybe a second more, but it makes the script portable. It's better to teach people the proper way. ;)

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/env env bash`? ;) I know what you are getting at, and  I think I remember some rant of Linus regarding portability. Quoting wikipedia on [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29): »This approach may introduce vulnerabilities that expose information or gain unauthorized root access and does not grant complete portability.«

Comment: @AndersSjöqvist, so you think /usr/bin/env is more likely to be accessible than /bin/bash? /usr may not even be mounted while /bin always live in root partition

Comment: @knittl I heard this before, and no one has so far been able to explain to me why this is a problem. I followed the reference link from the sentence you quoted, but I don't think that link discusses this as a problem. What that page says is that you shouldn't let users define their own environment variables. But what if a user already managed to install a malicious script and change the environment variable? Why would he then need to exploit another program to run his script? He could just as well run it himself. Everything's run with his permissions anyway.

Comment: @Ineu Yes, I think that /usr/bin/env is far more likely to be there than /bin/bash, although I know that that's not always the case. On my system, bash lives in /usr/local/bin/bash. Should I create a symlink from /bin/bash, perhaps? Note that even the [Python Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/interpreter.html) states that you should use `#!/usr/bin/env python`, without even admitting that there might be another way.

Comment: Yes, in your case /bin/bash wouldn't work. But in this topic there's tag 'linux' and bash is very common shell in linuxes.

As for python manual, i wouldn't use it as extensive source of writing shell scripts. Python is not even closely so common in linuxes as bash.

Comment: @Ineu How can you tell just from the tag that the script should made non-portable? When I installed my BSD server, I had to port my scripts from my Linux machine, because no one had told me that I could have written the scripts in a better way. I followed all those "just write #!/bin/bash, it always worked for me so it'll be good enough for you" advice. Luckily, I had written the scripts myself and never sent them to anyone else.

Comment: @Ineu And about Python: Do you figure that Python is less vulnerable to exploits simply because it's not as commonly used for scripting? Note that I'm not saying that the way to make your script portable is to use the most common scripting language. I'm saying that a portable script should work without requiring any patching *once all the dependencies have been installed!*

Comment: @AndersSjöqvist No, I wasn't talking about expoits. What i wanted to say is that you would probably find bash in /bin directory on linux (if it's installed, but you can't use it if it's not anyway), while python can be installed anywhere: from repos to /usr/bin, compiled by hands to /usr/local, even to virtualenv.

About portability: one must make scripts portable if portability is _required_. If it is not i would care more about situation when /usr is not mounted than about using scripts on BSD. Latter could never happen and even if it would, it's not a big deal to change one line.

Comment: @Ineu Why do you unmount /usr? Does your system really work after that? My port knocking daemon is in /usr, so I wouldn't even be able to log on. Quick-and-dirty solutions often sound like a good idea at the time; "let's encode years with only two digits, this software will be replaced in one year and year 2000 is five years away!" Yeah right. When is portability ever *required*? It wasn't required when I used Linux, but at that time I had no idea that I'd need to run the same script on other computers as well. BTW, "changing one line" will be a big deal when someone else needs to change it.